# iframe HTML element unwrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is used for `<iframe>` HTML element unwrapping. Most of the lines are repeated. How can I simplify this function?

```
<span id="pc1430828456801" class="optins">new insert text</span><span id="pc1430828456801" class="optdel">perturbative</span>
```

I have the same ID for both classes. I want to remove `tag` and `innerhtml` for the element with `class="options"`. But in the element with `class='optdel'` I need to remove the surrounding tag only and retain text. How can I do this in the same function if both element `id`s are the same?

```
function Undotext() {
    try{
        var checkopttag = $('#main_iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("holder").parentElement.className.startsWith("opt");
        if(checkopttag === true){
            var r = confirm("Please confirm UNDO correction");
        if(r === true){
            var undoclassname = $('#main_iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("holder").parentElement.className;
            var undoidname = $('#main_iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("holder").parentElement.id;
            var elements = $('#main_iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.all(undoidname);
            if(undoclassname === "optins" || undoclassname === "optdel"){
                    if(elements.length === 2){
                      for (var i=0, im=elements.length; im>i; i++) {
                           $('iframe').contents().find("#" + undoidname).remove();
                          var $newText = $('iframe').contents().find("#" + undoidname);
                          $newText.replaceWith( $newText.text() );      
                      }
                    } else if(elements.length === undefined && elements.className === "optins") {
                      $('iframe').contents().find("#" + undoidname).remove();
                    } else if(elements.length === undefined && elements.className === "optdel") {
                      var $newText = $('iframe').contents().find("#" + undoidname);
                      $newText.replaceWith( $newText.text() );
                    }
                } else {        
                    var $newText = $('iframe').contents().find("#" + undoidname);
                    $newText.replaceWith($newText.text());
                }
        }
        } else {
            alert("Undo Not possible Here");
        }
    }catch(e){
        alert("Catch error: "+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Having two elements in the same document with the same `id` violates the HTML specification.

Comment: yes same id but different class.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Unless you correct that, you can't expect that anything involving the DOM will work. `id` is not just a generic field that you can put anything in; there are restrictions on what is allowed. It's supposed to be like a primary key in a database. You can't have duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I tried going through this code as written and had a very hard time understanding what you are trying to do.  It looks like you are doing a lot of repetitive DOM querying.  Also, your HTML is invalid. The `id` attribute **must** be unique on a page and you are breaking that principle.

So here are some tips to help clean up your code:

The easiest way to fix your invalid HTML is to switch your `id`s and `class`es around. It looks like you got these values backwards. `class`es can be duplicated; `id`s can't.

```
<span id="optins" class="pc1430828456801">new insert text</span>
<span id="optdel" class="pc1430828456801">perturbative</span>
```

Use an [IIFE](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-selector) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).  This will create a private scope for you and ensure that `$` is actually pointing to `jQuery`.  The easiest way to do this is take your entire code and place it inside this code:

```
(function( $ ) {
  // your code here
})( jQuery);
```

You should [cache all of those selectors](http://jsperf.com/why-cache-jquery-selectors).  This will simplify a lot of the code.  Also there is no reason to use jQuery to grab the element and then use vanilla JS to get where you want.  Since you are using an `id` to start just get it the [fastest way](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-selector) using `getElementById`.  For example:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('main_iframe').contentWindow.document;
var holder = iframe.getElementById('holder');
var parent = holder.parentElement;
var parentId = parent.id;
```

Remove the `document.all`.  That is IE specific and is not cross browser compliant.  If you followed the above advice then you should be able to use `getElementsByClassName('pcxxxxxxx');` to get those elements as a collection.

I would also remove the `if else`s.  An easy way to do that is to `return` out of the function after each evaluation.

```
if(elements.length === 2){
  //code here
  return;
}
if(elements.length === undefined && elements.className === "optins") {
  //code here
  return;
}
```

Make some of these changes and there may be further optimizations possible.